# Javascript creating array of arrays runtime

Tags: javascript

How to best create this in runtime?

```
var fields = ["abc", "def", "somepar", "otherpar"];
var toSet = "foo";
// How to genereate this variable from code
var valuepairs = [["Progress", progress], [fields[0], toSet], [fields[1], toSet], [fields[2], toSet]]; // [fields[n], toSet]
```

Regards

Larsi

Comment: What are you asking here? The code you gave here is completely valid. How do you need to use it?

Comment: @picardo: Seems pretty clear. He gives the inputs and asks how to programmatically generate the given output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.push` method to append to an array...

```
var valuepairs = [["Progress", progress]];
for (var k = 0; k < fields.length; ++ k)
   valuepairs.push([fields[k], toSet]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just the function I was looking for

Comment: @Larsi: fyi `valuepairs[valuepairs.length] = [fields[k], toSet];` works too, not that I'm particularly advocating it over this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var valuepairs = new Array(new Array('progress',progress)); //first line is hardcoded...
for (var i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
   valuepairs.push(new Array(fields[i],toSet));
}
```

Comment: Sorry I was a bit late accepting, but Kenny was first, so I'll accept his answer. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks Larsi. I am not here for the reps, just for fun. Good luck.